# TripAdvisor Content API - Listing more than 10 objects

Tags: php, tripadvisor

I have got an API key for TripAdvisor Content API and what I'm trying to do is get data for all (or at least 100) restaurants in a specific area.

I'm using this URL:

```
http://api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/location_mapper/45.81331,15.97751?key=API-KEY-mapper&category=restaurants
```

to get restaurants in Zagreb. This Lat-Long: `45.81331,15.97751` points to the centre of Zagreb, where there are more than 10 restaurants - but I still only get 10 results.

Is there any way to get data for more than 10 objects with TripAdvisor Content API?

Let's say I'm building tourist website and I'd like to show all restaurants in the centre of Zagreb.

Comment: The documentation (https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/documentation/location_mapper/) doesn't mention any restrictions on the results, or any parameters to control it. Nor does it mention the radius around the lat/long location for which which results will be returned. https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/FAQ/ and https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/destination-content/address-and-geocoding/ does mention that not all entries have latitude/longitude properties attached, so I guess maybe it cannot map some places against your co-ordinates.

Comment: ...Have you tried specifically requesting some of the locations you expected to be returned (you can find their IDs on the main tripadvisor website), requesting their content directly and seeing if they have lat/long properties, and if they are accurate? The purpose of the location_mapper call seems to be to let you check your known property IDs to TripAdvisor location IDs, rather than being provided as a way to do a geographical search.

Comment: The reason I mention this last point is because I'm not sure why TripAdvisor would let you, for free, use all the mapping data they have collected in order to build a site where the user can search for restaurants etc using TripAdvisor's data. You would basically be creating a competing website, taking business away from them, but using their data at no cost. I cannot see any business reason why they would provide such a service. That (plus the documentation wording) is why I think you have misunderstood the purpose of the location_mapper API.

Comment: They allow simple usage where you get data about a specific location, or check to confirm the location of specific items, because they may feel that actually helps to drive traffic to their site when people want to get more information. e.g. if a hotel owner wants to display their current TripAdvisor rating on their own website, it makes it possible to do that. What you seem to be attempting is just to make a TripAdvisor rip-off - and using TripAdvisor's own data to do it! I can't really see why you thought they would make that so easy for you.

Comment: @ADyson I tried multiple locations and it's always 10 or less then 10 results.
And I think you missunderstood my question.

Comment: I just want to show users how people rated restaurants, in city that I'm making website about, on TripAdvisor.

Comment: Yes but you're trying to basically search TripAdvisor for restaurants in a specific area, so you can display those results on your site. Which is exactly what TripAdvisor does. So I'm pretty sure they aren't going let you deprive them of all the potential site traffic (and thus advertising revenue) for displaying those results. As I said, they'd let you display a sample of results, or specific items, as way to encourage people to go to TripAdvisor and get more info. These types of APIs are not freebies to you and I, they are all part of the business plan.

Comment: Ok, maybe you are right. But do you know how to with Content API show more than 10 results with URL I gave you. Cause I only got 10 or less with every location.

Comment: No, like I said, there's nothing in the documentation suggesting what should happen, or any parameters to make it return that. And TripAdvisor don't provide any support for the API. If there was a way to specify the number of results to be returned I'd expect it to be documented. I'd guess it's a deliberate limitation (for the reasons discussed above), but unless someone who actually works on that API for TripAdvisor happens to come on here I'd be a bit surprised if you get any definite confirmation of why it's like that.